# Symfony 3 - Can't upload file on form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm using symfony 3 and I've created a simple form to get some company information, included company logo.

I'm able to create the form, upload the logo image, with the other values, save it on my database and move it to my specific upload folder. But when I come back on form (after flush the data) I got all my Entity values except logo values. I explain better because I've two problem with this process, but before I'm going to show my code.

this is my Entity `CompanyProfile.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use function PHPSTORM_META\type;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * CompanyProfile
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="company_profile")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CompanyProfileRepository")
 */
class CompanyProfile
{
    // properties ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="logo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     minWidth = 50,
     *     maxWidth = 800,
     *     minHeight = 50,
     *     maxHeight = 800,
     *     allowLandscape = false,
     *     allowPortrait = false
     * )
     */
    private $logo;

    // other method

    /**
     * Set logo
     *
     * @param string $logo
     *
     * @return CompanyProfile
     */
    public function setLogo($logo)
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }
}
```

Here my action

```
public function companyProfileAction(Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader)
{
    $fileUploader->setTargetDir($this->getParameter('company_profile_dir'));
    $companyProfile = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CompanyProfile::class)->getCompany();
    if ($fileName = $companyProfile->getLogo()) {
        try {
            $companyProfile->setLogo(new File($fileUploader->getTargetDir() . '/' . $fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException $fileNotFoundException) {
            dump($fileNotFoundException->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $companyProfileForm = $this->createForm(CompanyProfileType::class, $companyProfile);

    $companyProfileForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($companyProfileForm->isSubmitted() && $companyProfileForm->isValid()) {

        $companyProfile = $companyProfileForm->getData();

        /**
         * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $logo
         */
        $logo = $companyProfile->getLogo();

        if (!is_null($logo)) {
            // Generate a unique name for the file before saving it
            $fileName = $fileUploader->upload($logo);

            $companyProfile->setLogo($fileName);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($companyProfile);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', $this->get('translator')->trans('Information are saved'));

        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');

    } elseif ($companyProfileForm->isSubmitted() && !$companyProfileForm->isValid()) {

        $this->addFlash('error', $this->get('translator')->trans('Some errors are accured'));

    }

    return $this->render('setting/companyProfile.html.twig', array(
        'companyProfileForm' => $companyProfileForm->createView()
    ));
}
```

And here my upload services (the paramaters are setted on `config.yml` and `service.yml`)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $targetDir
     */
    public function setTargetDir($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->getTargetDir(), $fileName);

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDir()
    {
        return $this->targetDir;
    }
}
```

Now that I've show you my code I can explain my problems:

1. When I return on my action (no submit fired, only change page), the method `$companyProfile->setLogo($file)` called and at the beginning of the action change the value on my database (setting full path instead of the fullname) without execute `persist` and `flush` of the entity because I call them only if the form is submitted
2. However if I change manually on database the value before load and I set the file on my inputFile, the input is empty (in console `$('#<id>').[0]files` is empty)

Any solution?